# Commit changes after each iteration inside a function postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to commit the changes after each iteration inside this function to be able to save my progress in case of stopping the function in the middle of work. what should I do?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_in_loop() 
RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
    counter INTEGER = 0 ;
     i INTEGER = 0 ;
BEGIN
    i = (select COUNT("ID") from "AwsSesNotification"
            where "UTADateCreatedOn" < (now() - interval '3 month'))/1000 + 1 ;
    LOOP 
        EXIT WHEN counter > i ; 
        counter = counter+1;
        delete from "AwsSesNotification"
        where "ID" in(
            select "ID" from "AwsSesNotification"
            where "UTADateCreatedOn" < (now() - interval '3 month')
            limit 1000
        );
        RAISE NOTICE 'Counter: %', counter;
        RAISE NOTICE 'From: %', i;
        PERFORM  pg_sleep(2);
    END LOOP;
    return counter;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: You can use a procedure. But typically committing frequently does not make things faster in Postgres. The size of a transaction is no limiting factor in Postgres and the a transaction involving 1 row is essentially the same as a transaction involving a million rows. It's rather the opposite: 1000 transactions deleting a 1000 rows will most probably be slower than one transaction deleting a million rows

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They create much more problems than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 0):

This is known as AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTIONS and is unfortunately not supported in PostgreSQL.
The only way I know to achieve similar effects is by using dblink(), essentially writing to another database which has a separate transaction context.  Much slower than normal writing.

Best regards,
Bjarni

Comment: Autonomous transactions aren't required. This can be done inside a procedure, but I doubt it is worth the effort

Comment: I'd love to know how.  To my best knowledge nothing is committed and all operations will be rolled back in case of exception for example.

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson Just use a procedure with commits in it.  Procedures were added in postgres 11.

Comment: Very nice.  Thank you - I'll have to look into this new feature.

Comment: I use postgres 10.6 no stored procedure.